# Is it possible to run emacs under MSYS?

Tags: emacs

I'm using MSYS with mintty
is it possible to run emacs with it? This emacs should accept posix path's, etc.
I want to use path's like: /c/Ptogram\ Files/
Which build I should use?

Comment: What sort of POSIX path are you trying to pass Emacs?  It already handles things like c:/foo/bar natively.

Comment: When you say "should accept posix paths", what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean should accept forward slashes without the drive letter (in which case Emacs should do the right thing already provided you only have/use a single drive - once you have multiple drives, you need some way to specify the drives, and on Windows that involves going outside the posix specification). Or do you mean you expect Emacs to pretend some fictitious fake directories exist in the same way as MSYS?

Comment: Thank you guys. I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just run the standard Emacs build for Windows, and make sure it is in your $PATH.